# R crashes when evaluating Rcpp function

Tags: r, crash, rcpp

To reduce the run-time of my code I need to implement a knapsack solver function in C++ using Rcpp. When I call the C++ function from R, it works the first few times, but if I repeatedly call it R(studio) crashes (within the first 3 to 10 times I call the function). I have 3 years experience with R but none with C++. The knapsack solver function is below:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
// A function that returns maximum of two integers
int max(int a, int b) { return (a > b)? a : b; }

// Returns the solution of the Knapsack problem
//  [[Rcpp::export]] 
IntegerVector knapSack(int nItems, int size, NumericVector weights, NumericVector values){
    NumericMatrix matrix(nItems,size);
    NumericMatrix picks(nItems,size);
    IntegerVector chosen(nItems);
    int i,j;
      for (i=1;i<=nItems;i++){
            for (j=0;j<=size;j++){
                  if (weights(i-1)<=j){
                        matrix(i,j) = max(matrix(i-1,j),values(i-1)+matrix(i-1,j-weights(i-1)));
                        if (values(i-1)+matrix(i-1,j-weights(i-1))>matrix(i-1,j))
                              picks(i,j)=1;
                        else
                              picks(i,j)=-1;
                    }
                   else{
                        picks(i,j) = -1;
                        matrix(i,j) = matrix(i-1,j);
                    }
              }
        }
         while (nItems>0){
              if (picks(nItems,size)==1){
                    nItems--;
                    chosen(nItems)=1;
                    size -= weights(nItems);
                }
              else{
                    nItems--;
                }
          }
    return chosen;
}
```

I compile the function in my main R script using:

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp('<path>/Cfunction.cpp')
```

Then I generate the following data:

```
nrRespondents <- 1000
nrComponents <- 30
prices <- matrix(sample(0:100, (nrRespondents*nrComponents), replace=T),nrow=nrRespondents, ncol=nrComponents) 
budgets <- matrix(sample(300:500, nrRespondents, replace=T),nrow=nrRespondents, ncol=1) 
utilities <- matrix(sample(0:100, nrRespondents*nrComponents, replace=T),nrow=nrRespondents, ncol=nrComponents) 
i <- sample(100,1)
b <- budgets[i] #size
p <- prices[i,] #weights 
mu <- utilities[i,]
v <- mu-p #values
```

Finally I call the function:

```
knapSack(nrComponents,b,p,v)
```

My OS is windows 7, I have R version 3.2.0 and Rstudio 0.98.1102. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: the most obvious thing to look for would be array accessing problems; check for appropriate 0- vs 1-indexing and whether you might be going past the bounds of vectors.

Comment: You are misunderstanding what StackOverflow is for. We are not a "hey debug my function for me" service so expect this question to get closed soon.